# Multitasking in iphone?

Tags: iphone, ios, multitasking

I am developing the Game iPhone application, it has Music player and and few animation. The game is interrupted by a text message or call it is terminated.  It should pause the game until you click cancel. But While sound plays  if i receive the call or message, audio player is pause, after accept/decline call, it doesn't play continue. how to manage this? actualy the

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the [UIApplicationDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) reference.  There you'll see the various methods that are called as events beyond your control occur (such as a phone call coming in, etc.)

In your case I believe you want to override the `applicationWillResignActive` and `applicationDidBecomeActive` methods to handle pausing the game, sounds, etc. and restoring them.

UPDATE:  I found this blog post very helpful in understanding all the multitasking delegates:  http://www.cocoanetics.com/2010/07/understanding-ios-4-backgrounding-and-delegate-messaging/